# How to move entire /usr/ directory

Tags: rsync

I have `/usr/` on a different partition that I want to format. So, I want to move it onto my root partition. I tried running

```
rsync -avzr /usr/ /usr1/
```

Then I tried if for example `/usr1/usr/bin/mv` would work, and it was fine. So I did
umount -l /usr

With the intention to then replace the old usr drive. But, something went wrong and when I tried to do `/usr1/usr/bin/mv` again, I got `bash: /usr1/usr/bin/mv: No such file or directory` which is weird, because it definitely existed and was executable. Did I do something wrong, and is there a better way to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remount `/usr` if you can. If you can't you're going to need to boot from a rescue environment.

I don't think you ran the command you described. I think it's more likely you missed the trailing slash from the source like this

```
rsync -avzr /usr /usr1/    # DO NOT RUN THIS
```

This will have copied `/usr` as a directory name into `/usr1`, so `/usr/bin/mv` would have landed as `/usr1/usr/bin/mv`. You need to fix this by getting rid of the intervening `/usr`.

You can do this by following these steps. If at any point you get something different to what I describe STOP IMMEDIATELY and report (in your question) what you did and what message(s) were returned.

```
cd /usr1      # No output
ls            # You should see only 'usr' and 'lost+found'
mv usr/* .    # Notice the important trailing dot. No output
rmdir usr     # No output
cd /
```

Now try umounting and remounting

```
umount /usr
mount --bind /usr1 /usr
```

If this works you can update `/etc/fstab` to have `/usr` mounted from the device holding `/usr1` instead of the device holding the old `/usr`, and at a convenient moment reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

On a modern Linux system, most executables use shared libraries. To see which are used with the command

```
ldd /usr/bin/mv
```

Of special importance is the dynamic loader, something like `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. This path is hardcoded in the executable, you must make sure the loader is available under that path.

For the other libraries, you can use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr1/lib64
```

If your dynamic loader is not available, the GLIBC loader can be called as an executable, other loaders may or may not support this.

So you can use this to call an executable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr1/lib64 /usr1/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr1/usr/bin/mv
```

You may have to adjust paths for your system.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of munging is something you should **only** do from a rescue environment, booting e.g. the installation from a USB stick and using it's tools. At least Fedora installation media can be used this way, if your distribution's can't, they probably provide some sort of rescue image.

Ditto for diagnosing and fixing the mess you made.